# CSS Rounded Corner and Shadow Does not Work in IE or Chrome

Tags: css

I am using CSS Rounded Corners and Shadow and when I run it through debugging in Visual Studio through Chrome it works just fine but when I place it onto a server and try to access it through server via Chrome or IE it does not show the shadow nor rounded corners. Is something different between server side and virtual server provided  by Visual Studio? 
Thanks for your help in advance.

```
.greenborder
{
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px;padding: 8px; border: 2px solid #7F9F1A;
behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);
background-color :White ;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
}
```

**UPDATED**

```
-moz-border-radius: 15px; /* Firefox */
-webkit-border-radius: 15px; /* Safari, Chrome */
border-radius: 15px 15px 15px 15px; /* CSS3 */

padding: 8px; 
border: 2px solid #7F9F1A;  
behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);
background-color: White;

-webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
-moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888;
```

Comment: For IE, make sure you have <!DOCTYPE HTML>

Comment: I have placed <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> into my master page.

Comment: Use <!DOCTYPE HTML>. That is the HTML5 markup.

Comment: Tried <!DOCTYPE HTML> still nothing on IE

Answer (score 2):

You must use this styling to make it cross-browser compatible:

```
.rounded-corners {
  -moz-border-radius: 10px; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px; /* Safari, Chrome */
  border-radius: 10px; /* CSS3 */
}
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the reply. I tried the code above and it works with Firefox and Chrome but not with IE hmmm what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: it works so or so only in IE9, not it former versions, because they don't support border-radius. For IE9 you must explicit set all 4 corner-radi. 'border-radius:10px 10px 10px 10px;'

Comment: you have set a doctype and checked that the page is not displayed in quirks or compability mode?

Comment: I have checked compability mode and its all set to standard settings and I have <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> in my Master page but still does not show up... hmmm interesting.

Comment: Tried <!DOCTYPE HTML> still nothing on IE ah :(

Comment: This works in IE9 if the doctype is correct. Try lowercase html like Sven said

Comment: Tried both still nothing... Could it be something on the server side that could be causing this issue?

Comment: If I run it through Visual Studio while debugging via Internet Explorer it works... But if I place it onto the server and then try to access the website I get nothing.

Comment: @SvenBieder "For IE9 you must explicit set all 4 corner-radi" I don't think it's true. I have tested it and it works fine with just one value.

Comment: @Alireza Noori That is only personal experience, nothing scientific validated. Last time I have done that for IE, it worked only out with all 4 radi

Answer (score 2):

You can use a great little tool called [Prefixer](http://prefixr.com/index.php) to make your CSS cross-browser. Very easy to use, saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Thank so much for that link its awesome. But I got it to work for all browsers except IE7-8-9.

Comment: It **should** work in IE. I have used a similar code and got the correct result. Please post your code in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: as I mentioned Sven, If I run it through Visual Studio while debugging via Internet Explorer it works... But if I place it onto the server and then try to access the website I get nothing. Could it be something on the server side?

Comment: Take a look at the source returned by the server and the debug session. (Right click, View Source code). If they both return the **exact** same code, then there's no problem. Maybe a problem in your browser's cache, you could try and clear your cache to see if it works (I get that a lot in IE). Also pressing `CTRL + F5` works too but not always. My suggestion would be diggin into the returned HTML and CSS and comparing them. If they're the same, maybe you don't have a problem at all.

Comment: Hey Thanks again for reply. I have tried the CTRL + F5 and nothing also cleared all the cache, history, cookies... nothing, compared the server side source and debugging source and exactly the same and still nothing... aaaa :(

Comment: What I suggest is this: Post your code in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) website and let us check it out. If the code is correct, then you should look for other solutions. But posting the code there would certainly help you. Also you could create a *test page* with the similar code and post it on your server and see if it works. Sometimes a completely irrelevant code can mess up your design. (An element filling the corners maybe).